# Implementing a bloomfilter with expiring elements for streaming data

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm writing a dedup bolt in storm and currently in my implementation I am using a bloomfilter that is implemented using a BitSet. I need to be able to set a time for each bucket to expire and be able to set that position back to zero in the BitSet.  Currently as a rough implementation I'm using a HashMap to store hashedValue as the key and time created as the value.If I encounter the value again using the bloomfilter implementation I check the map to see if its passed its time to live and if it is I return that it is not a duplicate and update the map with the new time to live value. But this wont work in my situation since I will be dealing with a alot of streaming data and this has to stay in memory and has to work quickly.  The other issue is that the bucket in the BitSet technically never resets to zero after its ttl and I only check the ttl when another duplicate of the data comes in.

Comment: Really at the end I am looking for a way to lets say keep track of when a bit has been set in a bitset and give it a specific time to live where at the end of its life it gets set back to zero.

Comment: http://colinsurprenant.com/blog/2012/05/12/continuous-bloom-filter/  if I could implement something like the continous-bloom-filter